# How to display last 3 RECENTLY stored items in sqlite database - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

- In my app i am using **Sqlite** data base to store the data.
- The stored items are displayed in a table (Main table).
- Now i need to display **RECENTLY added 3** items in another table (RecentTable).
- I implemented recent table, but unable to display recently added data.

Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using an [auto-incrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and then using that to get the three most recently added items? Something like:

```
select      whatever
from        mytable
order by    auto_inc_column desc
limit       3
```